# Is there a recommended way to migrate JWT tokens?

Tags: oauth, jwt, auth0

I currently have an API, which uses HMAC to create the JWT tokens. Now I am migrating to using Auth0 and the new tokens will use RSA. Since the API now will accept RSA tokens, it won't respond to users who in their devices still have the legacy token.

My question is, is there a way to migrate the tokens, or is it normal for users to be logged out automatically when doing a migration of this type? I am currently using asp.net core to host my public api.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to accomplish this by calling .AddJwtBearer multiple times, each with a different name for the "authenticationScheme" parameter. Once that is in place, add those scheme names as policies for your controllers, for example:

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "customToken,auth0")]